# Declaring a class with a member of type CWnd and a CString parameter in constructor causes C2248

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-2013

Suppose we have a class declared as follows:

```
class A {
private:
    CWnd wnd;
public:
    A(CString) {}
    ...
};
```

Now create an object of `A`:

```
auto a = A{ CString{} };
```

The compiler reports:

```
error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
```

What is wrong in that code?

This problem has a workaround: changing the signature of the constructor to `A(const CString&)` would resolve the issue. But I want to know why that error is reported.

Answer (score 0):

The CWnd constructor is private. Suggest you derive a class from CWnd (or some derived class) and use a pointer as your member variable.  Create the window dynamically with one of the MFC functions intended for the purpose.

Comment: CWnd constructor isn't private. Also if I remove constructor parameter then the code compiles successfully. I think the problem is about copy constructors.